# Pg locks - thousands of rows with empty transactionid and pid

Tags: postgresql

One of my internal tool which is working with postgresql database, started throwing exception: out of shared memory. There is a hint 'You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction', I tried to set it to 128 but it didn't help. Figured out that after tool is running for some time, there are a thousands of records in pg_lock table. Rows remain there even after stopping the tool. What is strange for me is that pid and transactionid is empty. Most of rows have column virtualtransaction set to '-1/0', mode 'SIReadLock', granted 'True', locktype 'Page' or "Tuple'. What it can means, where should I start looking for an issue? Need to mention that tool is using prepared transaction. Query SELECT * FROM pg_prepared_xacts; return one row only. Postgres version 9.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, which requires plenty of memory to store SI locks, which have to be held even after the transactions commit.

Increase `max_locks_per_transaction` even more.

Comment: Thanks! Is it normal that so many rows left in pg locks table even after tool is closed?

Comment: Also, if read committed is enough, could changing isolation level is a good idea?

Comment: If you don't need `SERIALIZABLE`, you should not use it since it does not come for free (as you see). The locks shhould go away after a while.